# How to call a stored procedure without passing parameter?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've created a SP in mysql, where I will be passing one IN parameter 'val'. In the body part of the procedure I'm using if else condition with select statements having 'val' in where condition of the query. In one of the select query, I don't want to use 'val'. So how to call procedure for the condition which doesn't use 'val' parameter. Thanks in advance, Krishna

Answer (score 0):

Pass in a null value into your stored procedure and have your stored procedure detect a null and behave accordingly.

To call the stored proc with a null:

```
call my_proc(null);
```

Then inside the proc, here's how you "ignore" the parameter if it's null:

```
select ...
from ...
where ...
and (val is null or some_column = val)
```

Comment: Hi Bohemian, thanks for your response..could you pls. show it with a simple example then it would be very helpful..thanks again!

Comment: See edit to my answer. Hope it helps. Let me know if you need more.